# Single developer, using TFS, want to work from home and office, looking for guidelines regarding check in

Tags: tfs, remote-access

I use VS2012 and TFS and am the only programmer checking in code. Usually, I leave code on my machine until a change is complete and then check it into tfs. I'm not using branches or anything else clever.

Now I'd like to start working from home. I have tried RDP'ng to my office machine, but it's just not the same. I find the slight delay takes me out of the flow. I can install VS on my home machine and all the tools I use.

I'm looking for some guidelines or practices I should follow. If I write some code in the office, do I check it in every day? Shelve it? I need to be ready to work the next day from home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a simple solution, I would go for a trunk (release version) and (at least one) branch.

Every day (at least), you check-in to your "currentWorkBranch", or a specific branch if you're working on a specific point.

So you work on your code (home and work) from / to this Branch.

When you're ok with your code, you merge it into your trunk (can do this from home and work too).

By the way, I would do this even when working in a single place. Never keep your code just on your machine if you can avoid this !

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. My machine does get backed up every night, so I haven't worried too much about losing code in progress. Will have to remember to check in code to the working branch before leaving though!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use shelvesets.  I do not like to use checkins to **save work**.  In my opinion a checkin should represent a finished piece of work.

**Shelvesets** however are designed for saving work.  That is why this would make more sense to me.

Comment: I agree; shelvesets work well for this.  You do need some discipline, since you end up with parallel checkouts on both machines and it's easy to get out of sync, but it's a great way of saving work to the server *without* checking in.

Comment: I partially agreee : the concept is fine, but (to be pragmatic) shelveset are less "user-friendly" for a daily usage (get latest version is easier than "shelve-unshelve" GUI). For the need of the OP, I think this might be an argument. Anyway, just a point of view.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I agree about your usability point.  Shelvesets are a little clumsy when being compared to Get Latest.  I think your way is a better process.  As long as you treat the Merge from Branch -> Trunk as the Checkin (provide a detailed comment etc), then your way works well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would say that, if it's practical, branch for each distinct piece of work (or feature) and just get used to checking in smaller, complete pieces of work into that branch.  Many frequent check-ins will not only solve the working from home issue, but will also avoid some potentially painful merges (depending of the number of other people working on the same code base).

When the feature is complete it can be merged as a whole into the main code branch.

EDIT: Having just re-read your question, it occurs to me that you mean you are the only developer using the TFS repository.  My suggestion still stands though, not least because it's extensible.